# Remove Last Sentence From KimonoLabs Body Result

Tags: javascript, kimono

I am scraping content with KimonoLabs and one I have scraped the body of an article I would like to remove the last sentence in the body.

[Here is an attachment of the body I am trying to remove the last sentance from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZUys.png)

I'm not so great with vanilla javascript so I am a little confused on how I should go about doing this?

I am looking for someone who uses KimonoLabs to point me in the right direction.

Comment: So you just want to remove `Not anymore!`?

Comment: Yeah, or just the last sentence from any body that would be scraped.